Open CSV files in subsections using loop
Edit!
I am trying to create a loop to open CSV files.
I started of by creating multiple lists of files that I want to have opened in separate dataframes:
file_list_a = [f for f in os.listdir(csv_directory) if f.endswith(').csv') and f.startswith('a') ]

I have multiple of these list up until the known amount of data.
And here is part of my loop:
for file in file_list:
    if file.startswith('1',1):
        frame_a1[file] = pd.read_csv(
            csv_directory + file, skiprows=27
        ).drop_duplicates(subset=['prot_acc','prot_score','prot_cover'])
        combine_a1 = pd.concat(frame_a1, axis=0, ignore_index=True)

However, I would like to have the first step automated as well, since it is sometimes unknown till what letter of the alphabet needs to go (startswith('i'))
I tried something like this:
alfabet = list(map(chr, range(ord('a'), ord('z')+1)))
file_list = {} #when use these or {}
for i in alfabet:
    try:
        file_list[i] = [f for f in os.listdir(csv_directory) if f.endswith(').csv') and f.startswith(i)]
    except:
        pass
file_list['a'] #=fil_list_a

This created a dictionary of my files en when running the last line file_list['a'] is looks exactly like what I had in my manual version:
['a1 (2).csv', 'a1 (3).csv', 'a1 (4).csv', 'a2 (2).csv', 'a2 (3).csv', 'a2 (4).csv', 'a3 (2).csv', 'a3 (3).csv', 'a3 (4).csv', 'a4 (2).csv', 'a4 (3).csv', 'a4 (4).csv', 'a5 (2).csv', 'a5 (3).csv', 'a5 (4).csv', 'a6 (2).csv', 'a6 (3).csv', 'a6 (4).csv', 'a7 (2).csv', 'a7 (3).csv', 'a7 (4).csv']
However, I cannot seem to use this in my next code block to open the files.
I tried this for example:
readout = {}
for i in file_list:
    readout[file_list] = pd.read_csv(
        csv_directory + file_list[i], skiprows=27
    ).drop_duplicates(subset=['prot_acc','prot_score','prot_cover'])

But then I get "TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str"
I have looked at pages here on stack but I have not yet been able to find a solution, I hope my question is clear!
Thanks for all the help :) I found a next solution of my problem by getting rid of the dictionary and using a dataframe of dataframes! I added it below. As some might notice the if statement is under construction still, I am trying to make the code that it deletes empty dataframes for example my code goes till p and not z. I was able to combine this outcome with my pd.read loop!
alfabet = list(map(chr, range(ord('a'), ord('z')+1)))    
list = alfabet
readout = [[] for x in list]
for i,x in enumerate(list):
        try:
                readout[i] = [f for f in os.listdir(csv_directory) if f.endswith(').csv') and f.startswith(x) ]
                if #empty delete
        except:
                pass
`


What exactly is the filename pattern that you're interested in? Have you considered using the globbing functionality of a pathlib.Path instance?

You need a nested loop: (1) over for i in file_list (file_list should be named file_lists, since it contains lists of filenames. (2) over i - a list of strings: for file_name in i.

As an aside: Use from string import ascii_lowercase as alfabet to create the letters you are using.

@SIGHUP I tried first working with glob in the start up of my file, I noticed that I could easier get my code to work the way I am using above. In addition, to your first question: (I hope I understand it correctly) I am looping trough csv files going from a till p (but in other examples it could be either letter of the alfabet) all have files with a setup like a1 (2).csv and so on like in the list. I wanted to create separate dataframes, one with all the a's one with all the b's etc. Thus they should be split by their first character.

You should probably glob for a superset of filenames then, using a regular expression, refine the match.
AFAICT it looks like the filename patterns you're interested in are:
starts with a lowercase letter, followed by a digit (or multiple), a space, a left bracket, a digit (or multiple), a right bracket and finally a .csv extension.
You cannot glob based on regular expressions.
Ultimately, it looks like you want a dictionary keyed on filenames with DataFrames as values. If that's the case then consider this:
from pathlib import Path
import re
import pandas as pd
from collections.abc import Iterator
import sys

PATTERN = re.compile(r"^[a-z]\d+\s\(\d+\)\.csv$")

def genfiles(d: Path) -> Iterator[Path]:
    # glob uses Unix style pattern matching - not regular expression
    for file in d.glob("*.csv"): # glob possible filenames
        if PATTERN.match(file.name): # refine the match
            yield d.absolute() / file.name

type DT = dict[Path, pd.DataFrame]

def main(d: Path) -> DT:
    dfd: DT = dict()

    for file in genfiles(d):
        try:
            dfd[file] = pd.read_csv(file) # add other parameters as required
        except Exception as e:
            print("Unable to parse", file, "due to", f"'{e}'", file=sys.stderr)

    return dfd

if __name__ == "__main__":
    csv_directory = Path(".")
    dfd = main(csv_directory)
    # dfd is a dictionary keyed on absolute pathname with DataFrames as values


Thank you for your help! I have to take some time to look into and understand your answer because it is very complicated for me :) But still thank you for taking the time to help me out

readout = {}
for i in file_list:
    readout[file_list] = pd.read_csv(
        csv_directory + file_list[i], skiprows=27
    ).drop_duplicates(subset=['prot_acc','prot_score','prot_cover'])

for i in file_list will give you the keys of the dictionary (a, b, c...)
file_list[i] is giving you the list of CSVs ['a1 (2).csv', 'a1 (3).csv', 'a1 (4).csv',...]
You are missing 1 more loop to get actual filename because right now csv_directory + file_list[i] is, as the error said, "str" + "list" and not "str" + "str+
UPDATE:
Therefore, if I'm correct, you loop should be something like this
readout = {}
for files in file_list:
    for csv_ in files:  # <-- This is the missing loop
        readout[csv_] = pd.read_csv(
            csv_directory + csv_, skiprows=27
        ).drop_duplicates(subset=['prot_acc','prot_score','prot_cover'])

Also, take a look as I changed readout[file_list] to readout[csv_] as I think readout is a dictionary with all your CSVs. If you do readout[file_list] you will be overwriting all the time the same key (also the key will be the list of names)

Thank you for taking the time to look into it! I understand the first two lines you mention, however how should I have done the for loop like you mention in the third sentence? something like for i in file_list:   for x in file list something like this?

Yeah, that would be. Let me update the answer with that

thank you for implementing it! As you might have guessed I am quite new to this therefore this thought step was hard for me to immediately grasp :) now it is fully clear!
